# Remove class next to another class with coffeescript

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have a rails app with the following erb

```
<li>
    <div class="well well-sm">
      <div class="pull-left">
        <div class="itemtext-20 completed" %>
          <%= "01    " + item.name %>
        </div>
      ..
      ..
```

Outside of this there is a link to coffee script. The coffeescript does a number of things. One of the things I want it to do is remove the completed class for the itemtext-20 class (the itemtext-20 is dynamically created for each line)

To do this I have tried to include the following line

```
$(".itemtext-20").removeClass(".completed")
```

But this does not remove that class. I need to remove the class as it changes the font styling. Is there something that I have wrong with the coffeescript?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking or how you're calling the CoffeeScript. Is the `removeClass` in question inside a DOM-ready function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
$(".itemtext-20").removeClass("completed")
```

You should pass the CSS class name to `removeClass()`. There's no need to prefix the class name with a dot `.`